# How may I merge a dataframe with repeated index entries with one with unique index entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stata

I have two data frames as so

[image]

One of those dataframes has an index that is repeated and I would like to join them with another dataframe in which that is not so. For example

Dataframe I=

```
[ index  column1]
leb       Lebanon
iso        iso1
CAN         Canda
```

DataFrame I2=

```
[ index  column1]
leb       ra
CAN        ba
CAN         gell
```

I want to merge them such that

Dataframe Itot=

```
DataFrame I2=
[ index  column1     column2]
leb       ra          Lebanon
CAN        ba           Canada
CAN         gell       canada
```

It is a many-to-one merge in Stata, as can be seen in 
http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dmerge.pdf p.7.

Comment: I believe the default merge in pandas is many to one. You just have to merge by index. This should give you what you want. 
```df1 = pd.DataFrame(["Lebanon", "iso1", "Canda"], columns = ["column1"], 
                   index = ["leb", "iso", "CAN"])```  

```df2 = pd.DataFrame(["ra","ba", "gel1"], columns=["column2"], 
                   index=["leb", "CAN", "CAN"])``` ```pd.merge(df1,df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this DataFrame

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2010,2009,2008],
                       'population_A': ['101597.0', '101416.0', '101342.0'], 
                       'Country':['Aruba', 'Aruba', 'Aruba']})

    df = df.set_index(['Country'])
    df
```

Consider the other non-repetitive dataframe to be

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Aruba','Afghanistan','Africa','Lebanon'], 'iso3c':['ABW','AFG','AFR','LEB']})
df1 = df1.set_index(['Country'])
df1
```

To do so we need the first dataframe to have a different index than country say id 0,1,2, ...

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df
df.join(df1, on='Country')
```

this is it